# Run a .jar file on Unix always resolves in a NoClassDefFoundError Exception

Tags: java, unix, exception, jar, manifest

I am working on a little java program which I want to run on a unix machine.

First, I compiled the `.java` file without any errors.

```
javac CallACMDFromJAVA.java
```

Then my `.class` file was created.

```
CallACMDFromJAVA.class
```

Then I used the `jar` command to create an executable `.jar` file.

```
jar cfm cmd.jar manifest.txt CallACMDFromJAVA.class
```

So far so goo. The last cmd gave me a `cmd.jar` file. 
But when I want to run it, some error suddenly appears. I typed:

```
java -jar cmd.jar
```

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CallACMDFromJAVA (wrong name: serviceCall/CallACMDFromJAVA)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Do you need more information about java environment or something else to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is apparently in a package `serviceCall`. Ideally, you should make your source directory structure match the package structure, so you have the source file in a directory called `serviceCall`. Even without that, if you compile it with

```
javac -d . CallACMDFromJAVA.java
```

then that should create a `serviceCall` directory containing `CallACMDFromJAVA.class`. You should try to run this directly *before* putting it in a jar file:

```
java serviceCall.CallACMDFromJAVA
```

... that should work, whereas `java CallACMDFromJAVA` would fail with the same error using your existing workflow. It's always worth trying it *without* the jar file before putting it *in* a jar file.

You then need to change your `Main-Class` in the manifest to `serviceCall.CallACMDFromJAVA`, and create the jar file to include the `serviceCall` directory, e.g.

```
jar cfm cmd.jar manifest.txt serviceCall
```

Then it should work. Basically, you need your `Main-Class` attribute to refer to the fully-qualified class name, and you need the corresponding class file to be in a suitable directory within the jar file.

Note that if you use a good IDE, all of the directory structuring is likely to be handled for you.

Comment: Wow. I never read such a good answer! And it also worked!! :D
Thanks a lot!